# How to use Turkish toilet tap?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, local-customs, turkey, hygiene

I was in Turkey a while ago, and encountered sit toilets with taps (edit: taps controlling a nozzle a wee way below a normal western sit-toilet rim, making a little fountain from the back to the front inside the bowl). While I was brave enough to turn the tap on briefly, I was perplexed that the stream wasn't particularly forceful, so it's obviously intended that one uses one's hand, but since toilet paper was provided, I didn't need to experiment.

My question amounts to: how does it work? Is it basically the same leaning to one side to wipe? If so, do you follow up with soap both on hands and derrière, or... how do you know which towel to sully? (Edit: aside from it being a chilly experience, I don't want to end up with an uncomfortably and embarrassingly wet bottom or find myself having used over half a roll to get dry, or use the wrong towel, assuming there's one even there!)

Comment: Where is the tap exactly? Inside a bowl or right next to it? If latter, then just check the question suggested by hippietrail.

Comment: You have encountered a squat toilet. And it works just as it's described in the question this is linked as a duplicate to.

Comment: @Ankur he said "sit toilets with tap" so maybe he means [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_6NqiahIEU_o/StXJtFSSwfI/AAAAAAAAAA8/-qLARvVGCEE/s1600/IMG_0203.jpg)? In such case, it's not squat toilets thus not duplicate as far as I can understand. :)

Comment: Perhaps. @android.weasel, could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: I have voted to reopen. This is not about squat toilets, hence not a duplicate. See here: http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/details/Toilets.html

Comment: Cool. Definitely not a duplicate then, so reopened.

Comment: I wrote 'sit toilet', not squat toilet: this looks like a western toilet, but has a tap somewhere on the outside with a spout inside towards the back of the bowl pointing up towards the front from a few inches down from the rim.

Comment: you just turn on the water for a while until you see fit. then you wipe yourself with the toilet paper. you don't touch yourself. you will realize there are no "remains" if you did it right. hands or soap are not involved until you wash your hands normally afterwards.

Comment: Maybe related to this newer question: [Are the hoses in toilets in Asia something I should know about?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19790)

Comment: Funny question,  I wonder how to use  a non-squat toilet!

Comment: Is this different from a bidet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have seen these toilets in Indonesia a lot (in hotels, Malls...etc).  This type of toilet comes in different styles.

Some have a very forceful tap that can literally make a second hole in your butt or make the one you have wider! These types do not need any hands to help with the cleaning as the forceful stream will clean everything.  Some will be as you described very weak stream so it needs some help from your (non-dominant) hand to finish the job.

Always turn the tap slowly to avoid having the forceful stream make a mess of things, and never turn it on while standing and looking at the toilet so it won't hit your face! I tried that once out of curiosity, and it's not fun!!!

To use the tap to clean after you're done with your pooping, move forward a little so there will be enough space to slip your hand from the back and wash your butt. If you have small body and/or the toilet seat is big enough you can move back and slip your hand from the front. The front method can be a little bothering for males.

I don't think you can lean to one side, as doing that will move your butt away from the water stream and will make a hard job more difficult.

Answer (score 8):

It's very simple to use.

When you are done, use some paper to wipe the remainings just like you usually do.
Then use the tap to wash it WITHOUT using your hand in there. (use some paper to operate tap)
Then wipe with paper again until it's clean and dry.

That way, it will be more hygienic. Paper + water is better than just paper or just water.

Don't forget to wash your hands with soap. Use paper on taps and the door too :)