# How to clean yourself after you've used this style of western toilet in India?

Tags: india, hygiene, southeast-asia, toilets

I saw this type of toilet (see image 2) in North India. The commode is same as most of the others. But I couldn't find the **jet** (see image 1) which is generally attached with the seat.

So I'm wondering how do you clean yourself once you're done (image 2)?

[image]

Comment: Common in Finland too. Colloquially called (swearing warning) >! "pillupuhelin" ("pussy phone" in English). Never heard anyone say that in English except to translate the term.) I hope that's ok to say as it's relatively commonly used. Checked with google, 85000 hits. Also called "käsisuihku" though that also means regular, hand held showering shower, ("hand shower") with 153000 hits. "Ala(pesu)suihku" ("bidet shower". "down(washing)shower" literally), combined 2600 hits.

Comment: Jet "generally" attached to the seat? This is the first time I've seen something like image #1... perhaps be a bit careful about cultural assumptions. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

It's easy, use the hose! while you're sitting on the toilet seat, direct the hose to your private area (do not insert it there, of course), press and get yourself cleaned.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19790/are-the-hoses-in-toilets-in-asia-something-i-should-know-about) explains how to use the hose.

[image]

Comment: The Bum gun is a fantastic way of cleaning.

Comment: I don’t get how to use these. Do you take your pants and underpants off and squat and use the bum gun? Or do you use it while you’re sitting on the toilet seat?

Comment: While you're sitting on the toilet seat

Comment: do we need to be concerned about the leaking drain pipe, or is that a normal component of this setup?

Comment: @dlatikay I have never seen such a thing, I hope it's not connected to what it seems it's connected to in the photo..

Answer (score 2):

See the thing on the left. This is known as Muslim Shower. I guess mostly used by Muslims. It is used to clean your dirty areas.

Comment: Not related to Muslims. The hose is common especially in Southeast Asia and some other countries.

Comment: @Hermanto> fwiw, Southeast Asia features the largest muslim countries by number of believers.

Answer (score 0):

- crumple a bunch of toilet paper.
- Wet it up
- Use it on your private part after you done.

Pro tips : its better if you imbue the wet toilet paper with soap for cleaner private part.

Comment: There is no indication paper is available at all.

Comment: Or bring your own `Huggies`. And if they are used in the ISS (http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewnews.html?id=1194), then this tip is really a "pro" tip

Answer (score -1):

## Bidet

If you travel France, Portugal, Italy, Spain, Brasil, Argentina, try to look for this **specific device** which serves the purpose

[image: Bidet]

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. 'This western toilet'.

Comment: If "this" is to be interpreted too literally, the question would be too specific. There is no indication of presence of other furniture in the bathroom or what kind of venue the OP is staying (hotel? b&b?). "Western" bathrooms, at least in the countries I listed, *are often-to-always* equipped with a bidet. In other countries, if the venue is a large hotel they *might* choose to buy one to accommodate international travelers, at their discretion.

Comment: The picture with the question clearly shows the hand shower, which indicates the answer.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ there's a huge range of far more reasonable interpretations between "this one specific toilet" and "any toilet that might be considered western", without making the question too specific. OP is clearly hoping for an answer applicable to the toilet shown in the image, and this answer is not.